# Proof similarity of triangles?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

my task is to calculate $\sphericalangle CXY, \sphericalangle CYX, \sphericalangle XCY$. My instructor gave me the hint to proof (with basic geometric knowledge)  $\triangle ABC \simeq \triangle AHC \simeq BHC$. **If** that is shown, it follows $\sphericalangle BAC = \alpha = \sphericalangle HXY = \sphericalangle HCB$ and the same for the $\beta$'s. Can someone explain to me, for example why $\sphericalangle HXY = \alpha$. From that point its indeed obvious that $\triangle ABC \simeq \triangle AHC \simeq BHC$?    [image]

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the image in the OP, it is easily seen that $\triangle ABC \simeq \triangle AHC \simeq \triangle BHC$ since all three triangles have the same angles: alpha, beta and a right angle.

Comment: I think my question was misunderstood. The question ist why are the angles the same in the different triangles? So it has to be shown, that the $\sphericalangle HXY, \sphericalangle HYX, \sphericalangle ACH,\sphericalangle BCY$ are $\alpha, \beta$.